# Generate .php file rather than .html in docfx documentation

Tags: docfx

I have been generating documentation with Docfx and everything works fine. Docfx generates `.html` files which is as expected.

However, since `html` files an be embedded in `php` files, I am looking for a way to generate the files as `.php` files rather than `.html` which I don't find any information.

I need this feature because I use a PHP templating engine in my application and I wanted to insert template variables in the markdown files for PHP to resolve dynamic values when being loaded in browser.

If this is possible, I would want a guide on how to do this. For instance, if I could locate and modify the file extension in the source code where the files are created.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's no build-in feature for that. Since I ran into the same problem today, here's a small workaround to archive that (sample in powershell):

```bsh
$destinationRoot = "path/to/doc"

[RegEx]$Search = '(\.html)"'
$Replace = '.php"'

ForEach ($File in (Get-ChildItem -Path $destinationRoot -Recurse -File)) {
    (Get-Content $File.FullName) -Replace $Search,$Replace | 
        Set-Content $File.FullName
}
```

After that you have to rename the files via script, too (it's not part of that script). You can archive that via modify the `Set-Content $File.FullName` command. You may wish to delete the old file, too.

Keep in mind it will replace links in the content, too, if they end with `.html"`, but pages normally will not end with that extension, so it's an acceptable trade-off. If you really ran into that problem, just append a `#` or something else to the URL.